# Android Preference Summary in Preference Menu Not Persisting

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferences

I'm a bit unclear on how Preference.setSummary() is supposed to work. Is this method supposed to update a menu item's summary in a Preference fragment in a non-volatile way? In other words, is the displayed summary supposed to persist after closing and re-opening the preference menu fragment?

I thought it is supposed to work like this, yet any time I press the back button and then re-open the preference menu the summaries are blank again.

```
public class FragmentSettingsMenu extends com.takisoft.fix.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat {
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from the XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            if (key.equals("pref_wood")) {
                Preference woodPref = findPreference(key);
                String color = woodPref.getSharedPreferences().getString(key, "Maple");
                MainActivity.getGLSurfaceView().setTexture(color);
                woodPref.setSummary(color);                                                         // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
            }
        }
    };
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this method supposed to update a menu item's summary in a Preference fragment in a non-volatile way?

No.

> In other words, is the displayed summary supposed to persist after closing and re-opening the preference menu fragment?

No.

Comment: Do you have a link to an explanation for achieving persistence on summaries?

Comment: @Cody: You don't persist the summaries. You persist the data that lets you build the summaries. So, in this case, you need to run through your set-the-summary logic after `addPreferencesFromResource()` in addition to when the preference is changed.